# 'As' or 'While'

Tags: grammar, meaning, as

Please have a look on the following sentences:

> - **As** I get older I get more optimistic.
> - **While** I get older I get more optimistic.

In the example above, using 'as' or 'while' does not make any difference in their meanings at all, but in the following sentences:

> - **While** I am getting older I am getting more optimistic.
> - **While** I was getting older I was getting more optimistic.

I think whereas we have used progressive tenses in both above sentences, we cannot use 'as', because I think 'as' can be used only in simple tenses and 'while' can be used for both simple and progressive tenses simultaneously.
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As I get older I get more optimistic.

is OK.

> While I get older I get more optimistic.

Using simple present tense *get* after *while*, I don't expect action over time. You could say:

> While I go to the store, I will pick up some ice cream.

which is a more time specific action.

So your progressive tense example is better:

> While I am getting older I am getting more optimistic.

though more natural might be:

> While I am getting older I am **becoming** more optimistic.

Optimism is an attitude that naturally changes over time, so *becoming* is better in this example.

Comment: Thanks @user3169. But could you clarify if you mean that I have to use 'as' only for simple tenses (at least to make more natural sense in second person), and 'while' for continuous tenses? ;)

Comment: When you use "while" with the verb "get", yes. To me "get" implies a continuous action. For other verbs, that may not be the case, such as "While you are at the store, buy some beer.", where simple tense is fine. Check the definition [while](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/while) senses 2 and 3.

Comment: Therefore can we conclude in the following way:
"As I opened my eyes I heard a strange voice" = "While I opened my eyes I heard a strange voice"
Are both above sentences the same and natural?

Comment: In "While I opened my eyes I heard a strange voice", I imagine that it took some time for your eyes to open, which is not so logical. But if that were the case, the second one might be OK. "As I opened my eyes I heard a strange voice" is OK. It is kind of like the difference between *at the time* (as) vs. *during the time* (while).

Comment: Oh, based on my textbook they mean exactly the same, but according to your statements, I guess they not only do not mean the same, but also have different usages.
So I will remember ==>
"As: at the time " --- "While: during the time"