# as/while/during it goes through the workflow

Tags: phrase-request

Workflow is a sequence of steps through which a piece of work goes (from initiation to completion).

Let's say we are discussing some workflow:

> Do we register the time spent on each step **as/while/during** a piece of work goes through the workflow?

Which of "as", "while", "during" (if any) is correct?

Comment: ***during*** is completely unacceptable. Both the others are "acceptable", but personally I'd much prefer ***as*** rather than ***while*** here (for no particular reason that I can put into words).

Comment: What can I say? Presumably you'd also accept the definition *"while" means "during the time of being".* And I deliberately included the word ***much*** in my comment, to indicate that I personally would have quite a strong stylistic preference in this exact context.

Comment: I don't particularly like your "jargonny" use of the word ***workflow*** here, which certainly wouldn't be common enough to look at in Google NGrams. But [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=as+the+job+progresses%2Cwhile+the+job+progresses&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cas%20the%20job%20progresses%3B%2Cc0) shows that the adverbial phrase ***as the job progresses*** is relatively common (unlike ***while** the job progresses*, which doesn't even occur often enough to show on the chart).

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of "while" vs "as".](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65959/use-of-while-vs-as) Also [As, when or while?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/69514/), [The difference between “as” “when” and “while”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/83971/), and ['As' or 'While'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/36992/as-or-while) (and probably others).